# [meteor][0.6.*] no data displayed whereas it's available in console

Tags: meteor

I've an application that is published on meteor hosting using command :

```
meteor deploy spyermeteor
```

The application is rendered on [http://spyermeteor.meteor.com](http://www.github.com/Rebolon/spyerMeteor) but no data is used on client side.

I can see that application is running well on server-side if i do a :

```
meteor logs spyermeteor
```

I then check the browser console and i see that i can access database :

```
Annonces.find().count() // per exemple
```

How do you explain that reactivity doesn't work on client-side ? maybe something is wrong with my conception but on my computer (windows) and on a VM (Linux debian) it works well.
Any help is welcome.

The source code is available here http://www.github.com/Rebolon/spyerMeteor

Comment: It seems to work for me, on the browser I enter `Annonces.find().count()` and get `314`. What is the expected result?

Comment: In fact in the console it works (i can access to all data), but on the screen you don't see anything, whereas you should see a list of div block and a list of item on the right side of the screen (here is a sample: [http://www.tribu-richard.com/stackoverflow/spyermeteor-stackoverflow.jpg](screenshot))

Comment: You probably have an error in your code somewhere so the entire script is not able to execute since it will break at the point the error is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In production mode all files are concatenated and minified into one javascript file. If there is even a slight syntax error somewhere in your code the rest of the code will not execute.

Looking at your deployed site you have to split your client and server side code. I receive an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Npm is not defined
```

This is meant to only run on the server but the code where you use `Npm` is being run on the client when it should only run on the server. It would also cause an error in production mode but since the files are not concatenated & minified the error wouldn't stop other javascript files from running.

You can either move this code to a file in `/server` or into a `if(Meteor.isServer) {..}` block

It also looks like your code is made for <= Meteor 0.5.9. You should upgrade your local instance to 0.6.2 and look for all these exceptions in your js console before you deploy your app.

Comment: ok thanks for this info. While it was working on my server i didn't pay attention at this error. Thanks a lot !